# How do I consume python API?

Tags: python, api

I have this specific API: https://github.com/leandrotoledo/python-correios
How do I consume it on my code? (as it is a github api, there is no need for OAuth or stuff like that, just direct use)

Comment: you clone the project and put in your application folder. After this you import the module and call method like documentation of readme.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by consume the API?

Comment: One byte at a time.

Comment: @DanD. Too funny for words...  `:D`

Comment: Consume is the term we use in Brazil... For you guys, the correct term is "use" I guess... I just want help to make this implementation on my code structure... please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly access it across all your classes you can do a pip install. 
Simply clone this and then proceed to pip install.

```
git clone https://github.com/leandrotoledo/python-correios.git
cd python-correios
pip install .
```

Now you can use it in your python libs/classes. Like this:

```
from correios import Correios
```

Comment: Do I create my new python file outside the python-correios folder or inside?

Comment: once you pip install globally, your python file could be anywhere on your system

Comment: You're a beast! Thanks

Comment: One more thing... Is there any possible way to generate a .exe python file from a selenium project?

Comment: I think so ... look into 'PyInstaller'. You'd pip install that and then point it to your project like 'pyinstaller yourprogram.py'. good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: yep, por nada! :)

Comment: Ué, tu é BR? kkkk